# ClassNotFoundException when trying to execute a jar file in serenity-jbehave

Tags: serenity-bdd

I'm getting the error below:

```
Exception in thread "main"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:net/serenitybdd/jbehave/SerenityStories

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.serenitybdd.jbehave.SerenityStories
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a dependency conflict. Check that you are using the latest versions for all of the serenity jars.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer . i am using all latest versions of all serenity jars . i am pasting my pom file here if any thing wrong please correct it .

Comment: using <artifactId>serenity-jbehave</artifactId>
<version>1.13.0</version><artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version> 1.0.6</version><artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>

<version>1.2.4</version><artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.1</version>                                                                                             if any thing need to modify please let me know

Comment: problem fixed for me .its dependency conflict